# Как правильно протестировать библиотеку через xUnit?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, 1с, тестирование, xunit

Всех приветствую!

Я начинающий программист 1С. Сейчас есть задание по написанию тестов для библиотеки на С#. Так как изучил поверхностно только базу С#, то не совсем понимаю как правильно реализовать тест в плане синтаксиса.

**Проект следующего характера**:
На С# реализован аналог Типов,объектов 1С. Цель предоставить возможность пользователю раскрывать 1С на разных языках в будущем без проблем.

На данный момент я остановился на тесте класса "ТаблицаЗначений" и "ДеревоЗначений" (Это как Excel документ состоящий из Rows and Columns со своими значениями в ячейках). Все Методы и обращения,если что точно такие же как и в 1С только реализованы на C#.Что от меня требуется прекрасно понимаю, ниже распишу. Но так как плохо знаком с синтаксисом С# возникают сложности. Надеюсь на вашу помощь Уважаемые форумчане !

Собственно, что нужно проверить по пунктам:

**Создание "ТаблицыЗначений"**:

```
 dynamic ТзТест = new ТаблицаЗначений();
        ТзТест.Колонки.Добавить("Name");
        ТзТест.Колонки.Добавить("Id");

        dynamic Стр = ТзТест.Добавить();
        Стр.Name = "John";
        Стр.Id = 155;
```

**1) Добавление и удаление строк**. Я так понимаю, что создаём строку, присваиваем ей значение. Затем проверяем с помощью Assert.Equal,что я могу обращаться к этой строке. А так же когда удаляю эту строку,то не могу к ней обращаться. Получилось только с добавлением и то не уверен правильно ли это:

```
Assert.Equal("joHn", Стр.Name);
```

2) **Добавление и удаление столбцов**. По аналогии как и со строками. Опять же с добавлением вроде понял, с удалением не знаю как:

```
Assert.Equal("name", ТзТест.Name);
```

3) **Создание ошибки,когда создаю столбец с невалидным наименованием** (C# регистрозависимый, как я понял).Не знаю как в плане написания опять же.

4) **Создание ошибки, когда переименовываю столбец и пытаюсь к нему обратиться**. Не знаю как в плане написания опять же.

Это пример с созданием ошибки, где я тестировал тип "Структура". Думаю по аналогии надо так же делать?:

```
        collection.Вставить("Тест", 6);
        Assert.Throws<RuntimeBinderException>(() => { collection.Тест2 = 5; });
        Assert.Throws<KeyNotFoundException>(() => { var a = collection["Тест3"]; });
```

5) **Перебор значений циклом**, тут вообще впал в ступор.Моё представление:надо создавать много столбцов со строками и перебирая их в цикле выявлять есть ли они там вообще и правильно ли отрабатывает цикл. Нужно ли в таком случае использовать примерно такую конструкцию?:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ТЧтест.Количество(); i++)
        {
            switch (i){
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Надеюсь на Вашу помощь и заранее благодарю! 
С "ДеревомЗначением" думаю сам разберусь,если пойму как тестировать ТЧ.

Так же после этого предстоит протестировать класс "ОбъектСсылка". Тут я вообще растерян как это реализовывать.

Необходимо:
1) Проверить представление ссылки.
2) Проверить доступ к полям ссылки.
3) Проверить доступ к табличным частям ссылки.
4) Проверить отсутствие доступа к отсутствующим полям ссылки.

Comment: `dynamic ТзТест = new ТаблицаЗначений();` - не напрягает переключать язык через слово?

Comment: Нет. же 1с-ник. Можно по делу.

Comment: Ну с деревом ладно, а почему для таблицы не взяли стандартный DataTable? Там уже все это есть и протестировано. В конце концов, если хотите наименования кириллицей оберните его своим классом. По поводу тестирования, боюсь вопрос слишком общий, как минимум нужно понимать логику работы ваших классов, ожидаемое поведение и граничные условия. Постарайтесь сконцентрировать вопрос на каком то одном аспекте, который вас больше всего тормозит. Это даст возможность дать развернутый ответ желающим и исключит вероятность (довольно высокую), что вопрос будет закрыт как слишком общий.

Comment: Если необходимо, вы можете задать несколько вопросов с конкретными проблемами, это будет более эффективно в плане получения ответа и будет соответствовать принятым тут правилам.

Comment: Хотите сказать для каждой проблемы создать новый вопрос ?

Comment: @Intercititude да, просто иначе в ответе получится каша без конкретики. Просто представьте себе документацию, например, к понятной вам 1С без разбивки на разделы. Удобно будет искать в ней что-то конкретное? Мне нет, есть подозрение, что большинству тоже. Вот и тут так же.